# How to mount XFS filesystem in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mount, xfs

I am trying to mount a hard drive with an XFS filesystem on it in Ubuntu. It was originally formatted in a netgear stora NAS device.

I am using a command in ubuntu like this,

```
sudo mount -t xfs /dev/sdc1 /mnt/stora
```

The command craps out the whole operating system. The GUI closes, a command prompt comes up and the machine is useless from that point, I have to reset. The error is this,

```
BUG: Unable to handle kernell NULL pointer derefence at 0000000c
xfs_alloc_fix_freelist
```

So I take it there is an XFS module and there is a bug. I have installed a clean 11.04 Ubuntu, so is there perhaps some bug fixes for the XFS module?

Comment: Could you please post the output of fdisk -l /dev/sdb? I suppose the device for your partition may be /dev/sdb1 and not /dev/sdb.

Answer (score 7):

Regarding the output of the fdisk command, I would mount your partition using the following command:

```
sudo mount -t xfs /dev/sdb1 /mnt/stora
```

The error message you get comes from a typo: the device to your partition is `/dev/sdb1` and not `/dev/sdb`.

Comment: Right, that is not working. Should I expect some output from the command disk -l /dev/sdb1. Having said that I used that command after I had done the mounting. So after the mounting the folder mnt/stora is an empty folder, and the free space says '4.4GB' which is the same as the mnt folder, so the mount didn't do anything.

Comment: Also if I try umount /mnt/stora, umount /dev/sdb1, umount /dev/sdb they all say that is is not mounted. Which one is correct out of interest?

Comment: The command `fdisk -l` from my last comment was just to know the partition layout of your hard drive and to be sure that your xfs partition was located on `/dev/sdb1`. Using it after `sudo mount -t xfs /dev/sdb1 /mnt/stora` should not change anything to its output. Is the command `mount | grep /dev/sdb1` returning anything after you have mounted your partition with `sudo mount -t xfs /dev/sdb1 /mnt/stora`? If not, did you get any other error message when mounting the partition?

Comment: No error messages or anything. I was running ubuntu inside a VM, but now I decided to install it with WUBI. The result is that the mounting operation craps out in a completely different way. The GUI closes, and a command prompt comes up. Take a look at the question, I will update it.